# Java Spring Boot: project saves images in the wrong path and not display images when opening with IDE Intellji

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-tool-suite

I have a project, my project is multiple module project like in the picture below, I used SpringToolSuite(STS) to code this project, recently I switched to Intellji so I opened this project with the Intellji IDE

[image: Multiple module project]

When I open this project with STS, it shows the image in the browser normally, but when I open this project with Intellji IDE, it doesn't load the image in the browser.

I have a code that saves images, **when I use STS**, the images are saved    to a folder with the path: **"ShopmeProject\ShopmeWebParent\ShopmeBackEnd\user-photo"**

But **when I use Intellji IDE**, my image is saved to the path: **"ShopmeProject\user-photo"**

So I need someone who can help me to configure my project to run properly on Intellji IDE

Comment: how do you save the photo? May you show the related code snippet?

Comment: @kon I fixed it, I set Working directory as $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ in Intellji and It works perfect

Comment: @kon you can check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I'm following this step and it works perfect

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2: set Working directory as $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$

[image]